# Order git repositories based on the last commit date

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

I have a folder with git repositories in each subfolder

```
folder
./repo1    // last commit 1 week ago
./repo2    // last commit 1 day ago
./repo3    // last commit 1 month ago
```

I would like to rank the repositories based on the date of the last commit to see the most recent modified repositories

result

```
repo2
repo1
repo3
```

How shall I do that please ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for repository in ./*/; do
    git -C "$repository" --no-pager log -1 --all --format="%at $(basename $repository)" 2>/dev/null;
done | sort -r | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

This loops over repositories, using `git log` to retrieve the last commit timestamp and producing output in this form:

```
571228806 repo1
571043015 repo2
570539599 repo3
...
```

The list is then sorted in reverse and cut to remove the timestamps. Note that you can output more information about the last commit from each repository by altering the format string passed to `git log`.